# How to kill 20 Uruks in 2 minutes?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

In *Shadow of Mordor*, to kill one of the War Chiefs, you have to kill 20 Uruks in 2 minutes. I have trouble with this one.

The first time I tried it, there weren't enough Uruks to kill, so I had trouble reaching the limit. The second time I tried it, I managed to wait for an Uruk to call for reinforcements by lighting the flame, but at that point there were so many Uruks that it took some time to thin the herd.

So, are there any tips that could help with this task? I don't have trouble staying alive; I have trouble killing them fast enough!

Some things that I've thought of, is using the Combat Finisher more liberally (where you hit X + Y on the Xbox controller to insta-kill an Uruk). There is also an upgrade for 2500 M which allows you to use an unlimited number of insta-kills, but I don't have enough M saved up yet to buy that.

Also, if I release a Caragor and it kills a Uruk, does anyone know if it would add to my count?

Comment: Caragor kills do add to your count, but caragors aren't that fast at killing anyway. A better idea might be to ride a caragor. You might be able to manage 20 kills that way with some liberal use of headshots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both answers posted provided some helpful tips. However, I already had most upgrades (up to Tier 4), so that wasn't the problem for me.

But, using the exploding barrel really helped. What I did specifically was, I first killed some Uruks near the reinforcement flame. Then, I didn't kill everyone; rather, I let at least one Uruk get away so he could signal for reinforcements. Once 20 Uruks came at once, I lured them towards the barrel, then shot it with an arrow. That killed about 15 of them in one shot. You are immune to the explosion yourself. After that, taking out the rest was a piece of cake.

As for the War Chief himself, I had to run around on the rooftops a bit first until the reinforcements "disappeared" (they literally vanished from the map). Then I took the War Chief on with only him, his bodyguard Captain, and a few straggling Uruks. This allowed me to take him out pretty easily; he is particularly vulnerable to Combat Finishers.

Comment: I didn't know we were immuned to explosions caused by ourself. Thank you for the strategy.

Answer (score 8):

Using `Detonate`, the tier 1 ability that make the fires and barrels blow up can get you 10+ kills in one shot.

Also, using the elf ranger shots to do headshots on enemies. Once you're out of shots (depending on how much you have), just make sure there are some arrows nearby and quickly grab them before continuing the carnage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the ability called Critical Strike (Doubles Hit Streak gains on
well-timed attacks). 
Simply press the attack button when you previous strike lands and you will get double hit streak points and be able to use the Combat Finishers more often. 
This is the fastest way I've found without having a lot of the higher tier skills. 
If you've gotten further than tier 2 check out these skills:
Tier 3: Swift Finisher - Reduces time required to perform Ground Executions in combat.
Tier 4: Blade Master - Reduces Hit Streak threshold for special moves from 8 to 5. 
Tier 4: Resilience - Ability to absorb one hit without resetting the Hit Streak counter. 
Tier 5: All of the ranger skills.

Answer (score 0):

The timer doesn't start until you start fighting so if you get a cross going then release the caragors you can user the distraction to get quick stealth kills or fight a small group